# Android/iOS - How to build an app which will be called only when you want to attach an image?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, attachment

Firstly I am not a native english speaker so I had trouble to find how to explain my issue. Please apologize.

So I want to build an app which will be called only when you want to attach an image to a message (text, mail, etc..). Like the gallery or camera app.

The user will choose a specific content in my app then I will return the selection to the app which called mine.

Is that possible to do that ? I am looking for the answer on both platform: iOS/Android. (Edit: I have skills in both Java and Objective-c programming).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for android, you would have to use an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) which will tell the phone that your app can be used for specific purposes, such as a browser, music player, file explorer, etc. In your case, you will need to use the [CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY) intent filter which will let your phone know that it should be an option for selecting pictures.

You'll need to add something like this to your android manifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY" />
</intent-filter>
```

EDIT: How to send the image to the other app:
You need to use an intent with the ACTION_SEND parameter to send binary data like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Comment: Alright, but I am not* seeing how you "return" an image from the app ?

Comment: You could use an Intent to send binary data to the other app. I added some sample code in my answer. For more info on sending data to other apps, look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Great, thank you!So as the other comment is saying, I can only build this kind of app for Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of software is not currently possible with iOS. The prevalent paradigm in iOS is content "sharing", as in the user picks the content he wishes to share, and options are presented to him (such as sending an email, message, Facebook, etc.). There are currently no interfaces (not counting Jailbreak) which allow you to extend the native mail application, or service it directly.

Comment: This is what I thought with iOS, thanks. Edit: I can just thumb up one answer, I will choose the first comment but anyway ty.